# Is 1/2" plywood adequate for a slab overlay?

Tags: basement, subfloor, basement-refinishing

I am planning to take the 1" EPS + plywood sandwich approach to my basement subfloor (pergo on top). I've read conflicting things around the plywood -- is 1/2" ply sufficient? Do I need to do two layers of 1/2" to get to a full 1"?

Comment: I'm not sure why you wouldn't go with standard 3/4" (nominal) tongue and groove plywood. I wouldn't want movement at the seams.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend any wood based subfloor (plywood, osb, particle board, mdf, etc.) in direct contact with your concrete basement floor without first putting down some sort of moisture barrier. I just ripped out an old OSB subfloor (glued right to the concrete floor) in my tiled basement and it had large patches of thick black mold in many places. Many laminate floors suggest use of under-layments that can act as a moisture barrier. If you ever get water in your basement you will regret a wood based subfloor down there (regardless of a moisture barrier installed or not the subfloor will retain moisture for long periods of time). Why not just use a floating floor approach with the underlayment below the pergo?

Comment: Extruded polystyrene is an adequate barrier, no? Especially if the seams are taped.

Comment: Yep I'd consider EPS as a decent moisture barrier, but it works better as insulator. My point is throwing osb or plywood on top of EPS will work but if a pipe breaks or your basement floods, that subfloor will mold for sure. Pergo is not a nail down/ staple application so what's the point of the plywood?

Comment: thats a good question.. I want the EPS for insulation, this area gets absurdly cold. I figured pergo right on top of EPS was not going to be rigid enough?

Comment: You should call Pergo and make sure it won't void their warranty, but I think you could forgo the plywood and do eps alone if you got the high compression kind .  Not all EPS is created equal (it all depends on how hard they compress this stuff at the factory). Some have compressive strength up to 100 PSI  which are used for load bearing and under slab applications. I couldn't imagine this stuff flexing the tongue and groove of Pergo even under high loads. Dow makes tongue and groove EPS too. http://www.owenscorning.com/NetworkShare/EIS/58307-G-FOAMULAR-400-600-1000-XPS-Product-Data-Sheet.pdf

Comment: Just to be clear, there is nothing technically wrong (violating Codes or anything as far as I know) with plywood/OSB over EPS either, I just don't like wood based subfloors in a basement for the reasons outlined above.

Comment: I think you should edit your question to clarify what you've stated in the comments. I nearly downvoted (but didn't) because of the statement without a moisture barrier... which the OP clearly IS intending to use.

Comment: @DaveInCaz I believe you've misread that: "without _**first**_ putting down some sort of moisture barrier." [emphasis added] Sorry about the double negative in the sentence :)

Comment: @gdodbiscuit yes I missed that, sorry!

Comment: 'I don't recommend any wood based subfloor in direct contact with your concrete basement floor' full stop.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to understand what you are doing...

Concrete literally wicks moisture like a sponge. Right now, your bone dry basement floor is wicking moisture from underneath your home and depositing it into the air in your basement. Do not completely cover any concrete floor which is in contact with the earth with any type of moisture barrier or wood.

If you cover the floor with a moisture barrier, then moisture will get trapped between the moisture barrier and the top of the concrete which will create a beautiful place for mold to grow.

If you cover the floor with wood, then the wood will soak up the moisture and hold it until it grows. The entire thought reminds me of an elementary science experiment involving lots of mold.

You can do the following:

2x2 floor panels are available at the hardware store. They have corrugated plastic on the underside with OSB on top. The corrugated plastic allows air to flow between the concrete and the OSB. Air flow is all you need to allow the moisture to escape. Do not run the subfloor all the way to the wall. Make sure air can flow so that the underside can stay dry. You can put anything you want on top except for ceramic tile which requires a very solid floor, like concrete.

Carpet can be glued to the concrete. It will wick the moisture quickly. Do not install a moisture barrier pad underneath. If you want a pad, make sure it will wick the moisture.

You can ceramic tile the floor. It will remain hard and cold, but it will look a lot better.

A coating of epoxy to seal the concrete might be a solution to the moisture. I have never tried it. In my experience, nothing can stop moisture from coming up through concrete.

Note: If your basement floor has dampness problems, then use a dehumidifier and leave it exposed.

Oh... In reference to your two layer question...

The subfloor does not need to be rock solid for a floating floor, but if it flexes with basic walking, then it is to soft. You are putting insulation underneath the 1/2" OSB. You can put one layer down and test it, but my bet is that you will need a second layer whose seams do not align. Your best bet is tongue and groove, but if you have certain materials, then make do. t will just take more because one layer would probably work if it was 3/4" tongue and groove.